# Selenium webdriver error (ruby) when launching headless chrome on Heroku since Chrome version 85

Tags: ruby, selenium, heroku, capybara

Question was closed for being a duplicate:

1. this issue is in ruby, not python and
2. I tried the solutions on that thread, nothing changed. Edited my question add that.

I have a Heroku app running the buildpacks:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/

and

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

I have the same setup as described on the chrome buidlpack:

```
chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil)

chrome_opts = chrome_bin ? { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_bin } } : {}

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(chrome_opts)
  )
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
session = Capybara::Session.new(:chrome)
session
```

I'm using the gem

gem "selenium-webdriver"

This worked perfectly fine until Google Chrome was updated to version 85 in September 2020. Now it succeeds roughly one out of 5 times, the other four times I get this error:

```
    2021-02-07T12:43:42.670067+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-1uto WARN: Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670068+00:00 app[worker.1]: from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670069+00:00 app[worker.1]: from tab crashed
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670070+00:00 app[worker.1]: (Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.150)
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670150+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-1uto WARN: #0 0x55e07c1cf199 <unknown>
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670151+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:72:in `assert_ok'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670152+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670152+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `new'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670153+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:88:in `create_response'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670153+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:114:in `request'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670153+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670154+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670154+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670155+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:220:in `set_window_rect'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670155+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:183:in `resize_window'
2021-02-07T12:43:42.670156+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/window.rb:123:in `resize_to'
```

I have tried adding additional arguments to chrome (even though the buildpack adds them automatically) to no avail.

I have added both the arguments on this solution:

unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium

And the issue remains.

```
chrome_opts = { "chromeOptions" => { "binary" => chrome_bin#,
                                          args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox disable-dev-shm-usage]
                                          } }
```

But still no luck.

So my question would be either:

```
How do I tell the buildpack to stick to chrome version 84? or

How do I avoid the error from happening on version 85 and above?
```

Thanks

Comment: Enter capybara tag when you raise the question related to capybara, people those are answering capybara will search only that tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app, browser: :chrome,
    options: Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage])
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

This made it work.